# Crystal Reports different versions on pc and on server

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I'm building a winforms application using a crystalreportviewer control (version 10.5.3700.0). Application works fine (it loads report from resources and displays it fine).
But when I put my application on server (other pc) that has runtime in versions 12.0.1100.0 and 12.0.2000.0.
My application isn't showing at all, even errors don't show :/

I was trying to use dll's in version 12.0.1100.0 in my application by removing references and adding new, but this generates errors.

I can't install runtime 10.5 on server.

Is it possible to add controls in version 12.0.xxxx to visual studio 2008?
How to do that?

I think that if I use version 12.0.xx controls in my application it will work fine.

Please help!!!

What I have done:

I have removed Crystalreportviewer control from toolbox and added new one from dll containing version 12.0, but no luck. Visual is adding control, all references, but control isn't visible :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best solution is installing same runtime on the server.
Anyway, you can use this XML in your app.config or web.config:

```
  <runtime> 
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="xx.x.xxxx.x" newVersion="yy.y.yyyy.y"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="xx.x.xxxx.x" newVersion="yy.y.yyyy.y"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="xx.x.xxxx.x" newVersion="yy.y.yyyy.y"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        ...
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

where **oldVersion** is the version you use for development and  **newVersion** is the version installed on the server

Comment: I was trying that, but I need to be aple to add control in version 12.0.1100.0 to my form. If I replace dll's with new ones I and add control to form is is not displaying, it is just like a clock control. Any ideas with that?

Comment: Sorry, never used 12.0 controls, try if in a new blank project it works.. anyway if you don't solve that way, bindingRedirecting will allow you deployment on the server. Good luck!

Comment: My application gets ID as an argument and then it displays empended report on form. Any hints how to create an application in 10.5 that will work on server with runtime 12 installed? Any links, sample projects mayby? :)

Comment: It works! :) app.exe.config worked, I had version mismatch first time I was trying this solution. crystalrepotsviewer looks different, but it works, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have use CrystalReports, but for web. And I faced the same problem. CR is very boring about the versions and other stuff.
Our solution in here was keep the 10.5 version and install on the server the same version.
But, maybe these links could help you in some way:

To download only packages of CrystalReports:
http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp

To look for any kind of CrystalReports downloads:
https://websmp230.sap-ag.de/sap%28bD1wdCZjPTAwMQ==%29/bc/bsp/spn/bobj_download/main.htm

Comment: What I have done it to remove Crystalreportviewer control from toolbox and added new one from dll containing version 12.0, but no luck :/

Comment: Humm, ok. Doesn't show any error? The page that generate the report, can you access it? What does happen when you access the page?

Comment: As I was saying before I'm doing a winform application :) Is it possible to replace that control in toolbox with new version?

Comment: Ohh yes, for sure. When I say 'page', I want to say 'form'.. But yes, you can. In the 'Choose items' in toolbox, you have to uncheck the current CR control checkbox, and then click OK (To make sure that we removed the current control). Then you have to check the CR control checkbox of the new version, that you have referenced the right dll, in 'browse' of 'choose items'. I think you already did this, right?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that :/ I'm choosing items from GAC, mayby because I don't have any files in C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\4.0\managed\dotnet2. Mayby if I had those files it will work? Do You mayby know how to get them? Are those the same as in runtime? I'm using CR version 10

Comment: Probably it will. Yes. Web it's the same. When you install the runtime, it will put the dlls into this directory that you mentioned (in my case, C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\2.8\managed). You can try to add directly from there, then your application will use the dll that you reference, not the gac.

Comment: In 2.8\managed\ are dll's in version 10.5, but as I was writing before when I try to run my application on server with runtime 12.0.xx it isn't starting and don't show any errors :/