# Crystal Report v10.5 toolbar not visible on Firefox but visible on IE and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, firefox, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am using crystal report v10.5 with visual studio 2008 to develop crystal reports.The problem I am facing is with the toolbar which is not visible on Firefox but it is visible on IE and Chrome. 
I have installed same version on both development machine and on production server which is Crystal report v10.5. My development machine is Windows 7 32bit and production is Windows 2008 64bit.

I have tried solutions mentioned on numerous forums such as

1. Copy the 'aspnet_client' folder from 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot' to 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\your-website-name'.
2. create a new virtual directory in your web site and point it to "C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/aspnet_client".
3. Application pool is to be changed to "Classic" instead of "Integrated".
4. Set the application pool of your application to operate under LOCAL SERVICE permission.

But still I am not able to show toolbar on Firefox.

Configurations:

- Visual Studio 2008
- .Net Framework 3.5
- Crystal Report for runtime 10.5
- Windows Server 2008 64bit

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Edit- I recently upgraded from Windows 2003 to Windows 2008 and the same version for CR 10.5 was working as expected without any mentioned solutions above.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried updating the CR for VS to the latest version? They are up to 13.x now and that may have to do with your issue.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have checked their wiki and the version above 10.5 does not support 64bit operating system.

Comment: Crystal Reports is a 32 bit application, there is no 64 bit version. Please see this thread for more info and download. http://scn.sap.com/thread/1519581

Comment: I understand that but the version I am using is supported on 64bit Windows 2008 and it works as expected with chrome and IE.

Comment: If it's FF only, then I would suspect that you have some security setting enabled that prevents VS and CR from rendering properly. Apparently you are not alone: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963126

Comment: I had already checked that forum and there is no solution for the same.As suggested by you I tried upgrading CR runtime to v12 which installed fine but CR for VS 2008 have dlls with version 10 and CR 2008 Service Pack 3 is paid so I am stucked in between v10 and v12.I am facing the same exact issue mentioned here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481898/vs2008-and-crystal-report-2008-issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `ClientTarget="uplevel"` to the page directive of the aspx file.

```
<%@ Page ClientTarget="uplevel" ... %>
```

Comment: I tried this but everything seems to be as is. Could you elaborate more. My reports are not working properly on IE 11 and Firefox

Comment: man so many thanks to your piece of advice..its now working on all browsers.. Many many thanks..

Comment: I had this issue in a CMS (Dotnetnuke) and fixed it by adding this to the root "default.aspx" file. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are compatibility issues between CR and certain browsers depending on the version of CR. There is a very helpful post [here](http://scn.sap.com/message/11093349) that has links to a compatibility table. I suggest to check that out and then see if you can maybe upgrade to a different version of CR.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding and providing links but the article is covering v11 which is not compatiable with .Net3.5 and VS2008..

Answer (score 0):

My application use last Crystal Runtime on x64 server and work on firefox too.

1) If the toolbar is not visible **there should be a reason** (press F12 in firefox.. what do you see? 404 error? 500 error? Please post it!)

2) **Crystal Reports Runtime 13.x IS available for X64 servers too**.. There is no reason to use an old runtime containing many bugs resolved in other releases.
 [You can get it here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)  (get MSI 64 bit - Support Pack 8)

After updating runtime you have to **copy the 'aspnet_client' folder again** fi you did (new virtual directory in your web site is a better approach)

After updating runtime you could need a little hack to let an **application developed with older dll work with new dll**. There are few rows you have to put into web.config [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600605/crystal-reports-different-versions-on-pc-and-on-server/9602469#9602469).

Comment: Thanks for responding.

1.No server errors in Firebug and Fiddler. 
2.I am planning to upgrade to it soon but for the time being I need a solution.
3. Already copied aspnet_client folder in application root folder and created a virtual directory on the same but still its not working

Info- In IE11 if I change user agent string it works and shows design as expected.When switched to Firefox and IE11 default it gives me the design without toolbar and horizontal and vertical line